# In my situation, what would be the most reasonable way for me to be able to use my "real connection" on demand?

Tags: windows-10, networking, openvpn, network-interface, socks

I have one computer, with one network port. I have no wifi. It runs Windows 10. It's connected (via the wall cables) to my NAT router and from that to the "fiber box".

I have OpenVPN installed, which I have set to automatically connect to my paid-for VPN on boot. When surfing (Pale Moon), and using all my other software, I instruct each software to use a SOCKS or HTTP proxy given by that VPN service, changing the country as needed. Those proxies (perhaps obviously) only work when you are connected to the VPN.

Now, in certain situations, I'm forced to use my "real connection". For example, the dating site "Plenty of Fish" shows fake error messages about the username already being taken (literally no matter what you pick) whenever I try to register an account while connected to the VPN, regardless of the proxy I pick.

I strongly suspect that it would allow me to register if I were using the "real connection". That is, bypassing my VPN connection for that particular task.

Somebody might say for me to "just disconnect" from it temporarily. But this is just an example; it's not feasible for me to keep disconnecting and reconnecting all the time, and I wish to solve this once and for all.

Now, I have already figured out that, if I specify a specific network interface for a connection to use, for example, in cURL (if you know what that is), I can bypass the VPN connection. So that's good, in theory. The problem is that Pale Moon (and other browsers, which aren't an option anyway), much like most software, have no support to specify what network interface to use. This is an extremely rare feature. So, I'm stuck with just being able to pick a proxy.

To me, it seems like I would have to somehow "create" a local proxy called something like `myrealconnection`, which I then specify as the SOCKS proxy in Pale Moon, and which simply "routes" the data to the specific network interface. That sounds perfect and simple in theory, but I've been stuck for years now without being able to figure out how exactly this would be done.

I also wasted a long time trying to find some feature in OpenVPN for this. It doesn't exist, or, if it does, it's impossible to find information on it or to get answers about it.

Can you think of a way to accomplish this? Or better yet, some other solution which I haven't thought of which spares me all of this headache? I'm completely stuck at this point.

Comment: I could be wrong, but most sites recognize/block VPN simply as a result of someone — of the 1000s of users sharing that VPN IP — having done something naughty (spam, or whatever). Purchasing a residential static IP (shared with only a handful of users) might resolve the issue.

Comment: @DigitalDracula You did not read my question...

Comment: Are the sites well-defined that you would to directly connect to? Meaning that you know their IP and there aren't too many of them.